# jQuery resume setInterval timer on keystroke

Tags: jquery, timer, setinterval, keystroke

I have a jQuery setInterval function named "timerIncrement" that times out (stops incrementing the variable [licount]) after x-seconds.  to resume this interval I have a .mousemove function which looks like this:

$(this).mousemove(function(){
 licount = 0;
 timerIncrement();
});

what I'm looking for is a way to do this exact thing (resume the timerIncrement function) if a keystroke is made.

Can someone please help with this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).keypress(function(){ licount = 0; timerIncrement(); });
```

By the way, if you want the keypress to trigger on the entire document, it may be better to use "document" instead of "this"... perhaps in both situations:

```
$(document).keypress(function() { licount = 0; timerIncrement(); });
```

See more [here](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/).

Comment: I was about to post exactly the same thing, character for character.

Comment: is there any way I can link the .mousemove and .keypress together without having to duplicate the code for both functions?

like $(document).mousemove or $(document).keypress....?

Comment: You could do something like:
function wakeup() = { licount = 0; timerIncrement(); };
$(document).keypress(wakeup).mousemove(wakeup);

Comment: thanks!!! I know I sound like a jQuery noob right now but everyone's gotta start somewhere...that being said, thanks alot for everyone's help!!